# How to setup DNS server per domain in Windows 7

Tags: windows, domain-name-system

in Linux I am able to easily configure dnsmasq (caching DNS daemon) to use particular DNS per domain. For example for all addressses *.home.lan it queries particular DNS server, but for all other it uses DNS servers determined from DHCP. This way I can work with various VPNs without mangling with primary and secondary DNS.

Is this possible also in Windows 7? I'd be fine to install some additional software or buy something. It could work similar way as dnsmasq. Unfortunately this excellent piece of software is written only for UNIX-based operating systems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Home questions are off topic, and product and service recommendations are off topic (http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).  Also, I think this is actually impossible, and I can't think of a single good reason to do it instead of subnetting properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be nothing like dnsmasq in windows but you can achieve what you want by using the Windows DNS Server:

Create a new primary zone in Forward-Lookupzones named `lan` on your primary nameserver (DNS1). In that zone create a new delegation named `home` and set the nameserver's ip (DNS2) you want to be authorative for that zone. Now if you ping test.home.lan on a computer using DNS1 as nameserver the first query for lan will go to DNS1 which will in turn tell the computer that it needs to contact DNS2 for `home.lan`. Then the computer query DNS2 to find out which IP belongs to `test.home.lan`.

Comment: Just one note before I leave this off: My scenario is SMB with customers having two VPNs, I used home.lan domain because I am using this setup myself and I also do not want to show real domains from that company. I am not using Windows as a DNS service, I am actually not using Windows at all - only on Workstations...

Answer (score 2):

To set your expectations, I will tell you that there is no Windows equivalent for dnsmasq and the best thing you can do in this situation is forward DNS requests from dnsmasq to your primary Windows DNS or AD server.

I don't expect anyone to come in here and prove otherwise... but I'm open to it... :P